# Limit only two session per user in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How to allow only two sessions per single account  to login in asp.net 
prevent three users try to access ; no more two users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)You can, by keeping track of users logged in, in your global.asax by using the Application object.

2)In the Session_Start method or your login method, you can check if the user is stored in the Application object.

3)On the Session_End method or in your logoff method, you'll need to remove the user from the Application object.